# Difference between bind and onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

Most guides I have seen use the onBindViewHolder method to include data in a View inside of a recyclerView. I have always been using the bind method. Is there any difference? Or is it the same for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)
```

Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. (this method you override to get the position of the item)

```
viewHolder.bind()
```

Just a method that you create to separate things, could be anything

Comment: Interesting, mine only contains holder.bind(position);

Any reason I shou pu all my code in here instead of in bind()?

Comment: in your adapter you don't have a method called onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Yeah I do but it only contains holder.bind(position), nothing else. Everything that happens is in viewHolder.bind()

Comment: ok, but you could delete your view holder class and put it as an innerclass inside your adapter, then you could do everything inside onBindViewHolder

Comment: look this example: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: I know I can, but is there any reason to do so?